# Supporting Huawei IAP for multiple build types

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

Following the Huawei [official docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSInAppPurchase/index.html#0) I was able to integrate IAP into our app. I am able to query product details and perform a subscription, so the integration is working fine for the **release** build. However, we have multiple build types, imagine: **com.app**, **com.app.beta**, **com.app.debug**

To support multiple build flavours I did the required changes as adviced [per docs here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-config-flavor).
This however, it's not enough to have IAP on **beta** builds for example. Any interaction with Huawei SDK on beta build results in: `CERT_FINGERPRINT_ERROR = 6003`, which makes sense, because the SHA256 registered in the Huawei console is the one for the release certificate, not the one for the beta certificate.

The question I have is how to register a new pair of **com.app.debug/SHA256 for beta certificate** so I can test IAP also on other build types?

Now, I know, this can be avoided by signing the beta build with the release certificate, like this:

```
buildTypes {
    beta {
       signingConfg.release   // <---- use release config 
 
       // .....
    }
}
```

but this is more like a workaround than solution. Ideally we should be able to regiter a new app with a new fingerprint. How this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you use the **same** package name but **different** signatures in the **debug**, **beta**, and **release** environments, configure all the signatures in AppGallery Connect.
   [image: same package]
2. If you use **different** package names and signatures in the **debug**, **beta**, and **release** environments, you actually have three apps.

In this case, you need to create the apps in AppGallery Connect and configure corresponding signatures.
[image: Add Apps]

When creating an app, you can select a project that contains apps in other environments to facilitate unified management.
[image: creating an app1]
[image: creating an app2]

You can view and modify the configurations of different apps in the same project, as shown in the figure below.
[image: same project]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer @shirley! In our case we have the second scenario: different package names and signatures. OK, I understand that I have to create two more apps, but I don't see where to configure their corresponding signatures, i.e.: where to introduce the sha256 fingerprint of these apps? From what see, the signature configuration is done at project level, or am I missing something?

Comment: @AndyRes Yes, to configure the signing certificate fingerprint, you can click **My projects**, and click the desired app name. Then go to **Project settings** > **General information**.  Please refer to [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/config-agc-0000001050196065#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050196065__en-us_topic_0000001050043543_section19713716202718?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: I think I understand what's wrong on my side... the other apps that I have create were not added to the project, therefore I don't see them in the drop-down list. I will re-create them and make sure they are added to my project. Thank you once again, your feedback was very valuable!